# Connecting the SignalR console client to the server on Azure

Tags: c#, signalr, signalr-hub, signalr.client

I want to deploy a server (on Azure) using SignalR.
And the console client, so that it accepts commands from the server.

The server code was taken from here: https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/aspnet/signalr/overview/getting-started/tutorial-getting-started-with-signalr

Example of a console client from here:https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/804770/Implementing-SignalR-in-Desktop-Applications

```
using Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client;
using System;

namespace SignalRClient
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            IHubProxy _hub;
            string url = @"https://signalrchatmsdn20210410135946.azurewebsites.net/";
            //string url = @"http://localhost:62545";
            var connection = new HubConnection(url);
            _hub = connection.CreateHubProxy("BetHub");
            connection.Start().Wait();

            _hub.On("ReceiveLength", x => Console.WriteLine(x));

            string line = null;
            while ((line = System.Console.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                _hub.Invoke("DetermineLength", line).Wait();
            }

            Console.Read();
        }
    }
}
```

If I run the server locally, everything works (string url = @"http://localhost:62545";)
If I run the server on Azure, it works through the browser. But the console client throws an exception.
System.Net.WebException

Comment: The issue may be TLS authentication that is used for a HTTPS connection.  The best way of determing if it is TLS issue is to use a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler and capture the connection.   TLS is done before the HTTP Request is sent.  So if you see the Request than the TLS is good and you need to capture the HTTP response and see if the status is 200 OK or a 400/500 failure.  If there is no HTTP Request than the TLS version will be seen in the sniffer and you need to find out the version of TLS that is being used when the browser work and the version when the c# fails.

Answer (score 0):

[jdweng](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5015238/jdweng) absolutely right.

In my case, it was enough to change the deployment setting.

TLS\SSL settings => HTTPS Only: Off